# Centering Navigation and aligning drop down content accordingly

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues regarding a navigation bar using only HTML and CSS. I want to know how to get my navigation bar centered and how I can display my drop down content where it should (under services). Also, i want the hover over effect on "services" but I can't seem to make it work. Can anyone point out where my code went wrong? Below is my code.

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */


/*CHECK*/

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

ul ul a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/*Show the dropdown menu on hover for services*/

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown_content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav style="height: 60px">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html" class="dropbtn">SERVICES</a></li>
    <ul class="dropdown_content">
      <li><a href="beauty_services.html">BEAUTY SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="styling_services.html">STYLING SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="book.html">BOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: where are the services you mention?

Comment: Do you want a horizontal bar?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to the code.  Explanations are in comments.

```css
nav ul {
  /* Remove list bullets from menu */
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
  /* cosmetic: you won't see red text on red background :) */
  /*color: red;*/
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container needed to position the dropdown content */


/* This isn't used, so we don't need it */


/*.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}*/


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */


/*CHECK*/

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* move it down to avoid overlapping the button */
  margin-top: 16px;
  /* align it to the button */
  margin-left: -40px;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* float the main items (and only those) to create a horizontal bar */
nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

ul ul a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/*Show the dropdown menu on hover for services*/

/* + combinator selects adjacent siblings, in this case the dropdown */
.dropbtn:hover+.dropdown_content,
.dropdown_content:hover {
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown_content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav style="height: 60px">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="services.html" class="dropbtn">SERVICES</a>

      <ul class="dropdown_content">
        <!-- Put the dropdown items into one <li> with the dropbtn, makes hover effect easier -->
        <li><a href="beauty_services.html">BEAUTY SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="styling_services.html">STYLING SERVICES</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="book.html">BOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe below code will help you as what you want i made some changes of your code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
  /* cosmetic: you won't see red text on red background :) */
  /*color: red;*/
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}



/*Show the dropdown menu on hover for services*/
.dropdown_content  {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-content  {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown_content > li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav style="height: 60px">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="services.html" class="dropbtn">SERVICES</a></li>


    <ul class="dropdown_content">
      <li><a href="beauty_services.html">BEAUTY SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="styling_services.html">STYLING SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="book.html">BOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i just added this four line of code in style

```
.dropdown_content > li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
.dropdown_content  {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
```

and added `<div class="dropdown">` element for dropdown

Comment: You need to edit the code according to his requirements. Otherwise you can post this as comment.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I really did manage to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible help:

- Sample in horizontally aligned
- Shows when placing on top of Book or Service
- Contains an extra line drawer

```css
/*Style for when the container class is displayed*/
.dropdown_content {

    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
position: absolute;

    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Style in charge that when we put the mouse on top of him, we show him the hidden*/
/*Show the Service list*/
#dropbtnService:hover .dropdown_content {

    display: block;
}

/*Show the Book list*/

#dropbtnBook:hover .dropdown_content {

    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown_content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/*The other code has been deleted due to the number of errors that occurred*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;

    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-align: center
}

div > ul {
    padding: 20px;
}

div > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

nav > ul > li, div {
    float: left;

    padding: 1em;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */

ul ul a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    /* Remove list bullets from menu */
    list-style-type: none;
}

 #dropbtnService {

    background-color: red;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">


</head>


<body>
<div id="main">
    <nav style="height:60px">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <!--Modify and agree div's-->
            <div id="dropbtnService">
                <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                <div class="dropdown_content">
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="beauty_services.html">BEAUTY SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="styling_services.html">STYLING SERVICES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
            <div id="dropbtnBook">
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

                <div class="dropdown_content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="book.html">BOOK</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```